# Deep Linking to PWA doesn't work through redirect to another domain

Tags: push-notification, frontend, service-worker, deep-linking, progressive-web-apps

I work with an external service which serves my push notifications.
I have a problem with deep links, when trying to integrate it with PWA.

Algorithm: push received -> click -> external href opens in browser (catch statistics) -> redirect to my website

I configured web manifest, and it works fine in other situations. 
I think that Chrome has higher priority after redirect.

What can I do with this?